# How to disable bounce emails in exim?

Tags: email, imap, exim, email-bounces

How to disable bounce emails in exim ?

I don't want the server to send a bounce message when the email not exists.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Bounce is sent when message can't be delivered - i.e. there is no appropriate router for delivery. If you definitely sure you want to drop all messages for non-existent recipients, you have to add the very last router:

```
dropper:
        driver          = accept
        transport       = null_transport
        no_more
```

But I'm not sure it's a wise choice. If someone do a typo in the legal address he will never knows about it.

Way better is to check recipients at the RCPT stage in the ACL.

You can do that this way:

```
acl_rcpt:
. . . . .
require domains   = +relay_to_domains : +local_domains
        verify    = recipient
. . . . .
```

If incoming message have recipient doesn't listed in your user-DB, that message will be denied to submit. The only minus of that approach is that you have to be familiar enough with `exim`'s ACL, as far as that rule should be placed in the proper place within ACL.